# Defining maven dependency for JBoss 5.1.0 GA

Tags: maven, jboss

I'm migrating a legacy project to maven, right now I have some classes that depend on this **org.apache.log4j.Logger** class. I am sure that this class is provided by the **JBoss AS 5.1.0 GA** in which it is deployed. But I don't know what **groupId**, **artifactId** and **version** specify for this *provided* dependency. Do you have some idea of which ones are the correct values for this version of JBoss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post it is, `1.2.14` version. You can add like below.

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/242961

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.14</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```